# How to set the value of private variable in a super class using mockito or powermockito

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I have three classes A, B and C Where A is abstract class, B is also an abstract class and B extends A and C is non-abstract which extends B. I have variable by name AddressService addressService which is public in class B and is private in class A. I am writing a test case for class C which is non-abstract and calling method which is in class A and in class A i need to set the value of AddressService addressService variable which is used to invoke a method. AddressService is an interface which has methods and i am invoking one of the method in my super class A. Following is my code

```
public interface AddressService{
void test();
}

public abstract class A{

    private AddressService addressService = (AddressService) ServiceLocatorBeanFactory.getService(AddressService.class);

 public void createDocument(){
 addressService . test();
}

}

public abstract class B extends A{
public AddressService addressService = (AddressService) ServiceLocatorBeanFactory.getService(AddressService.class);
}

public class C extends B {
}
```

Here is my test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ServiceLocatorBeanFactory.class})
public class createTest {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public void createTurnaroundDocument() throws Exception{

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceLocatorBeanFactory.class);       

        AddressService addressService = Mockito.mock(AddressService.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ServiceLocatorBeanFactory.getService(AddressService.class)).thenReturn(addressService);

        C original = new C();
        C handler = PowerMockito.spy(original);
        handler.createDocument();
    }
}
```

I tried setting the value of AddressService addressService present in class A which is abstract in multiple ways but still the value is null and i get NullPointer Exception.

Following are the different ways

```
1.Whitebox.setInternalState(handler, AddressService.class, addressService);
```

When i set this way the value is not set and is null and gives me NullPointerException

```
2.MemberModifier.field(A.class, "addressService").set(A.class, addressService);
```

When i set this way i get the following exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set AddressService field A.addressService to java.lang.Class

```
3.Whitebox.setInternalState(A.class, AddressService.class, addressService);
```

When i set this way i get the following exception

org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException: No static field assignable from "AddressService" could be found in the class hierarchy of A.

```
4.Whitebox.setInternalState(A.class, "addressService", addressService);
```

when i set this way i get the following exception

org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException: No static field named "addressService" could be found in the class hierarchy of A.

Is there a way where we can set the value of private variable present in the super class using Mockito or PowerMockito. Please help

Answer (score 1):

```
MemberModifier.field(A.class, "addressService").set(A.class, addressService);
```

This is wrong: `java.lang.reflect.Field.set` needs an instance of your class if you want to set a non-static method, not the class. Might still not work, perhaps you will have to use `setAccessible(true)` on the field first:

```
Field field = MemberModifier.field(A.class, "addressService");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(c, addressService);
```

You can do the first line with pure reflection anway...

```
Field field = A.class.getDeclaredField( "addressService" );
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(c, addressService);
```

But of course, the big mystery is: Why do you have the same variable twice? Smells like bad code. Make the inner one protected instead of static, it's very unlikely that something good will come from having two.

Comment: As per your code field.set(a, addressService); what is this "a", where is that value from

Comment: what values does "a" hold . Is it the instance of Class A ?. Also My class A is abstract as i have already mentioned

Comment: Sorry, should be "c", since your Object c is the A object we need.